# Shell: Header doesn't stay at the top when apended in .CSV

Tags: macos, shell, awk

I use:

```
find "$Original" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' | 
awk -F/ 'BEGIN {print "Total Images"};{print $NF};'  >> "$ServerImageFlow"/SS1.csv
```

If I run it ONCE, it logs any files within specified folder into .CSV with Header "Total Images".

[image]

But if I run it a few times, the Header doesn't stay at the top.

[image]

Comment: check difference between  `>` and `>>` .

Comment: I need to be able to append it. > creates new file everytime ;/

Comment: may be instead of begin you can try `awk  'NR==1 && $0 !~ /Total Images/{print} NR>1{print $0}'` >> abc

Comment: It doesn't create Header, but simply outputs full path to the file.

Comment: *Appending* is adding to the end by definition. Why would you expect anything added to the end to be at the top?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what word would you use instead? I think screenshots explain well my intention? I know what append is, but am still too noob to put all my thoughts in code. As such, how would you export all of the log/output of all filenames, without its path, into .csv first column. With header “Total Images” always at the top, even when script is run -n amounts of time, and just pollutes the same .csv with any new files which were added to the folders? Append is not an option? Please share your knowledge if you know a better option.

Comment: @Ryul, just don't add a header when the file already exists; only add a header *at all* when the file is completely new. `[[ -e "$outfile" ]] || echo "Total Images" >"$outfile"` at the beginning of your script, and stop the `awk` from trying to add a header at all (take the `print` line out altogether), and you're done. It seems too obvious to even write up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the header *before* you start `awk`, only if the output file doesn't already exist.

Though you don't actually need `awk` for this at all: GNU `find` can be told to only print basenames.

```
outfile="$ServerImageFlow"/SS1.csv
[[ -e "$outfile" ]] || echo "Total Images" >"$outfile"
find "$Original" ! -name '.DS_Store' -type f -printf '%f\n' >>"$outfile"
```

Comment: unable to use `-printf`

Comment: Then you aren't using a GNU version of `find`; that part of the answer is explicit that it only applies to the GNU implementation. You still can just take the `BEGIN {print "Total Images"}` out of your `awk`.

Comment: thanks!! based on your anwser I just created a simple if/elif without any `awk` ! works much faster on large amounts of data too!! `if [ ! -e "$outfile" ]; then
 echo "Total Images" > "$outfile"
elif [ -e "$outfile" ]; then
 find "$Original" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' ! -name '.uid' -exec basename {} \; >> "$outfile"
fi`

Comment: the above script wont add any filenames if file doesnt exist, it will only add "Header":
the below script does the job `if [ ! -e "$outfile" ]; then
 echo "Total Images" > "$outfile"
 find "$Original" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' ! -name '.uid' -exec basename {} \; >> "$outfile"
elif [ -e "$outfile" ]; then
 find "$Original" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' ! -name '.uid' -exec basename {} \; >> "$outfile"
fi`

Comment: I don't believe "avoid duplications" was part of your specification. If it had been, I would have suggested an answer using `comm`, per [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Answer (score 1):

```
outfile="${ServerImageFlow}/SS1.csv"
find "$Original" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' | 
awk -v hd="$(head -1 "$outfile")" -F'/' '
    BEGIN{title="Total Images"; if (hd != title) print title} {print $NF}
' >> "$outfile"
```

Comment: it outputs only the Header, seems like `{print $NF}` doesn't work. It doesn't output anything it `find` s  :(

Comment: If it produces no output that means it's getting no input. There's no magic involved - given input the script WILL print the last field from each input line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to print just the basename and append to the file, then check afterwards if the header is present:

```
f="$ServerImageFlow"/SS1.csv
find "$Original" -type f ! -name '.DS_Store' -printf "%f\n" >> "$f"
gawk -i inplace 'NR == 1 && $0 != "Total Images" {print "Total Images"}; 1' "$f"
```